# How to combine 2 select statements in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have table test2.it contains

### ID

```
    1
    4
    5
   10
```

now i found missing numbers in this sequence.with this query

```
SELECT min_ID - 1 + level mn FROM 
( SELECT MIN(ID) min_ID , MAX(ID) max_ID FROM test2 ) 
CONNECT BY level <= max_ID - min_ID + 1 minus SELECT ID FROM test2
```

output is:

```
MN
---   
2   
3   
6   
7   
8   
9
```

now i want to combine these 2 columns.I am unable to do this please help me.
i want output like

```
  1        2
  4        3
  7        5
  10       6
           8
           9
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (id) AS
SELECT  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH bounds ( mn, mx ) AS (
  SELECT MIN( id ), MAX( id ) FROM test2
),
missing (id, rn) AS (
  SELECT id, ROWNUM
  FROM   (
    SELECT mn + LEVEL AS id
    FROM   bounds
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < MX - MN
    MINUS
    SELECT id
    FROM   test2
  )
),
existing ( id, rn ) AS (
  SELECT id, ROWNUM
  FROM   test2
)
SELECT e.id, m.id
FROM   existing e
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       missing m
       ON ( e.rn = m.rn );
```

**Output**

```
        ID         ID
---------- ----------
         1          2 
         4          3 
         5          6 
        10          7 
                    9 
                    8
```